# Emacs 24 + Synergy client on Mac OS X, why doesn't the server's keyboard control key work?

Tags: emacs, synergy

I run synergy server on my Windows machine, and the client on my Mac.  When i used emacs23, all keys were recognized properly.  I just upgraded to emacs24 and now the control key from the Windows keyboard doesn't work, e.g. Ctrl-n or -f do not move the cursor down or forward, though the control key is still recognized outside of emacs.

Other notes:

- I have both machines' caps lock keys made into a second control key.
- When i hit Ctrl-n on emacs from the server's keyboard, it's as though emacs24 is stalling because nothing happens until i hit another key, e.g. a-z.

UPDATE: opened a bug ticket at http://synergy-foss.org/spit/issues/details/3324/

Comment: It's perfectly possible this is a bug. Historically, i have found all kinds of weird bugs with the keyboard and Synergy. Have you tried posting on the official Synergy Foss Question site?

Comment: Done: http://synergy-foss.org/osqa/questions/1892/emacs-24-synergy-client-on-mac-os-x-why-doesnt-the-servers-keyboard-control-key-work

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug in emacs. It's been fixed (as per your bug report), and the 24.2.1 version for mac works as expected with synergy for me.